# Not able to create import

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have integrated Marketing Cloud With Salesforce. I am able to access Emails etc while in Salesforce.

But when I try to create import activity in Marketing Cloud and select Salesforce objects and Reports I get an error (pic attached). "An active category with an ID -1 could not be found" [image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that you have followed the instructions to [Configure Marketing Cloud](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/first_time_configuration__connection_mc_admin/) explicitly. If you miss a step, this will result in unexpected behavior.

My guess is that you haven't configured the **Salesforce System User Username** for the specific user account that you are using to login into Marketing Cloud (refer to the 'Connecting Your Marketing Cloud Users' section in the above link).

Comment: Thanks Eliot, asked help @ Marketing Cloud and they fixed this.